# How to hide the data coming from backend when the conditions are the name is anonymous and the array inside array is empty in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a array of data coming from backend and my requirement is as follows:

1. I must hide the contents if the user name is `"from_user_name"` is `Anonymus`.
2. if the messages inside the array is empty.

So can anyone help me to solve these 2 conditions.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let message of activeMessages" (click)="showMessage(message)" [class.activeShow]="message.id == message_id">
      <span>{{message.updated_at  | date:'dd.MM.yyyy'}}</span>
      <img style="width: 40px;" [src]="message.from_user_image || '../assets/images/msg.png'"/>
      <p style="padding-top: 16px;display: inline;">{{message.from_user_name}}</p>
      <p style="padding-top: 10px;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;"><b>{{message.text}}</b></p>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

TS:

```
loadMessages() {
    this.service
          .getMessages()
          .subscribe(
            data => {
              this.messagesdata = data;
              this.activeMessages = data.filter(msg => msg.active == true);
              this.closedMessages = data.filter(msg => msg.active == false);
              if (this.activeMessages.length > 0) {
                if(!this.message_show) {
                  var test = this.message_show = this.activeMessages[0];
                  this.message = true;
                  this.message_id = this.activeMessages[0].id;
                }
                console.log(this.activeMessages);
              }              
            },error => {});
  }
```

Console:
[image]

Comment: You obviously know how to `filter` an array. So, do another filter (or two)!

Comment: Is there anyway, where in i can sort the items by putting condition over loadMessages?

Comment: I am not sure what a sort will do for this. Either way, you cannot do anything with this data until you have it inside the subscribe. If you want to change the API to filter out the messages so you don't have to on the client, that would be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this kind of behavior should be filtered from the backend, but in other case, this is the right code:

```
loadMessages() {
    this.service
      .getMessages()
      .subscribe(
        data => this.activeMessages = data.filter(msg => msg.active && msg.from_user_name !== 'Anonymus' && msg.messages.length > 0)
}
```